# How to get the installed application list that uses gps in android?

Tags: java, android

I have this code which returns a list of all installed application of a device:

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> list =pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
            results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm)
                    .toString());
            Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
                    .loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }
```

But now I want to get only those application in my list which uses gps service, as far as i learned that if I can filter the permission being taken in those apps then I can solve it, but dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use can use the below code snippet:::

```
PackageManager packageManager=this.getPackageManager(); 
List<PackageInfo> applist=packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
Iterator<PackageInfo> it=applist.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
PackageInfo pk=(PackageInfo)it.next();
if(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED==packageManager.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, pk.packageName)) //checking if the package is having INTERNET permission
{
results.add(""+pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
}
}
```